# opening and closing streaming clients for specific durations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background-process, twitter-streaming-api

I'd like to infrequently open a Twitter streaming connection with TweetStream and listen for new statuses for about an hour.

How should I go about opening the connection, keeping it open for an hour, and then closing it gracefully?

Normally for background processes I would use Resque or Sidekiq, but from my understanding those are for completing tasks as quickly as possible, not chilling and keeping a connection open.

I thought about using a global variable like `$twitter_client` but that wouldn't horizontally scale.

I also thought about building a second application that runs on one box to handle this functionality, but that seems excessive if it can be integrated into the main app somehow.

To clarify, I have no trouble starting a process, capturing tweets, and using them appropriately. I'm just not sure *what* I should be starting. A new app? A daemon of some sort?

I've never encountered a problem like this, and am completely lost. Any direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Although not a direct fix, this is what I would look at:

---

**Time**

You're working with time, so I'd look at what time-centric processes could be used to induce the connection for an hour

Specifically, I'd look at running a some sort of job on the server, which you could fire at specific times (programmatically if required), to open & close the connection. I only have experience with [resque](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque), but as you say, it's probably not up to the job. If I find any better solutions, I'll certainly update the answer

---

**Storage**

Once you've connected to TweetStream, you'll want to look at how you can capture the tweets for that time period. It seems a waste to create a data table just for the job, so I'd be inclined to use something like [Redis](http://redis.io/) to store the tweets that you need

This can then be used to output the tweets you need, allowing you to simulate storing / capturing them, but then delete them after the hour-window has passed

---

**Delivery**

I don't know what context you're using this feature in, so I'll just give you as generic process idea as possible

To display the tweets, I'd personally create some sort of record in the DB to show the time you're pinging TweetStream that day (if it changes; if it's constant, just set a constant in an initializer), and then just include some logic to try and get the tweets from Redis. If you're able to collect them, show them as you wish, else don't print anything

Hope that gives you a broader spectrum of ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem isn't in scheduling tasks, storage, or delivery (i can do all of those things) but rather how to spin up a long-running ruby task from the main app on demand and monitor it. updating the question for clarity

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks for the reply! As mentioned, if I find a way to help, I certainly will. Otherwise, I'm sure you'll handle it :)